# Define A Dynamic Window

Tags: loops, foreach, statistics, stata

I have variable `A` which is shown below. 
Now, I want to generate variable `B` based on variable `A`. I have repeated `10` in variable `B` till observation `5` in variable `A`. Again, I have `11` in variable `B` till observation `5` in variable `A`. This procedure will be replicated. What is the efficient way to create variable B?

```
A   B
3   10
3   10
4   10
4   10
4   10
5   10
1   11
1   11
2   11
3   11
4   11
5   11
5   11
1   12
2   12
2   12
3   12
3   12
4   12
5   12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give below code a try.

```
gen C = 10
replace C = cond(A[_n-1]==5 & A!=5,C[_n-1]+1,C[_n-1]) if _n>1
```